# Print or Retain output from each run of a loop in R markdown notebook

Tags: r, dataframe, output, report

I am trying to make a report on the data contents of each dataframe in a list of dataframes, by looping over the list and running head() and tail() on each one.  However, the output in RStudio to the notebook is always just the last one.

Example:

```
# Initialize Variables
list_of_df <- list()
dummy_v1 <- c(1:3)
dummy_v2 <- c(4:6)
dummy_v3 <- 1

for (i in 1:3) {
  dummy_v3 <- c(i:i+3)
  dummy_v3
  dummy_df <- data.frame(dummy_v1, dummy_v2, dummy_v3)
  list_of_df[[i]] <- dummy_df
}


# Illustrate my Problem

# I would like to print the following output into the notebook report in a for loop for each dataframe in list_of_df:
head(list_of_df[[1]])
tail(list_of_df[[1]])

for (i in 1:length(list_of_df)) {
  head(list_of_df[[i]])
  tail(list_of_df[[i]])
}

# output only shows the last iteration's head and tails.
```

In reality, I have 130 dataframes, each with around 700 timeseries observations of 116 or 117 variables, so I need to do this programmatically.  I want to get this output so that I can do a quick sanity check on the dataframes and then proceed with the timeseries analysis.
TIA for your help!

---

### Answer!!!

lapply is a funny function for us R newbies; the syntax doesn't explicitly pass arguments to the function that is applied.  The solution that worked for me was syntactically elegant:

```
Report <- function(x) {
  list(sprintf("Details of %s", names(x)),
    sprintf("Columns: %d", ncol(x)),
    sprintf("Rows: %d", nrow(x)),
    head(x),
    tail(x))
}

lapply(list_of_df, Report)
```

The output is not so elegant but it is workable and allows me to quickly peruse the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want separate output, use a `list` as return in `base R` without loading any external packages

```
lapply(list_of_df, function(x) list(head(x), tail(x)))
```

---

With `for` loop, it needs to be stored in an object

```
out <- vector('list', length(list_of_df))
for(i in seq_along(list_of_df)) {
    out[[i]][["head"]] <- head(list_of_df[[i]])
    out[[i]][["tail"]] <-  tail(list_of_df[[i]])
}
```

Or in a single line

```
for(i in seq_along(list_of_df)) {
   out[[i]][c("head", "tail")] <- list(head(list_of_df[[i]]), tail(list_of_df[[i]]) )
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.  The syntax of lapply is a little odd to me but this worked.  I've edited my question to include the working correct code.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise you against a loop based approach to time-series problems, look into the https://github.com/tidyverts packages and the https://www.tidyverse.org/ packages

Anyway you can solve this with a simple

```
library(tidyverse)
map(.x = list(head,tail),.f = exec,list_of_df)
```

Comment: For my fellow newbies, could you please explain the arguments to the map function?

Comment: Sure map takes a vector and a applies a function to it, exec executes a functions, so if you pass a list of functions to to map and the function is exec, we execute a list of functions, and then you only need to pass on what these functions will be executed on, in this case list_of_df.

Comment: This also works but cant be extended to a list as an argument map(list_of_df, ~ list(head = head(.), tail = tail(.)))

Comment: Took me a few readings to puzzle through that.  So syntax of map is: map(vector to act upon, function to act).  

In this case, .x = list(head, tail) defines the vector as a list of the functions that I want to act.
.f = exec tells map that it is to run the exec functions on the list, which translates to executing the functions on the list.

Probably just my newbishness, but I find R's syntax a bit convoluted.  Thank you though!

Comment: This does take some time to get used to maybe read my fizz buzz example to help you though? https://twosidesdata.netlify.com/2019/12/22/fizzbuzz-in-the-tidyverse/